# Send digits after connecting to a SIP call using TwiML

Tags: twilio

When connecting to a PSTN number you can have Twilio send DTMF after the call is connected using the sendDigits attribute on Number

```
<Response>
  <Dial callerId="5555555556">
    <Number sendDigits="www12345ww#">5555555555</Number>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

How could you accomplish the similar thing using the Sip tag?

```
<Response>
  <Dial callerId="callerId">
    <Sip sendDigits="www12345ww#">sip:alice@example.com</Sip>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`sendDigits` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/number#attributes-sendDigits) is only available to the `<Number>` TwiML noun.

So what you have above with [`<Sip>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sip) simply will not work.

You cannot add any other nouns (eg `<Number>`, `<Client>`) in the same `<Dial>` as the SIP. If you want to use another noun, set up a callback on the `<Dial>` to use alternate methods.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So would that be configuring `statusCallback` et al, then return twiML with a `<Play>` to get the same functionality?